# Position Order in vb.net

Tags: vb.net, position

I am working on a project that the person with the highest score will take position 1 the next person will be position 2. if two person for instance have same score they will be giving same position but next persons something else for example two score 65 both will have same position I.e 1 and the next inline will not be 2 instead 3.

Comment: Post your code on what you have tried so far so we can help debug.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This can be achieved via LINQ:

```
    ' Example user scores
    Dim userScores = {
        New With {.Score = 65, .Name = "Linda"},
        New With {.Score = 65, .Name = "Paul"},
        New With {.Score = 64, .Name = "John"},
        New With {.Score = 63, .Name = "Yoko"}
    }
    ' Transform user scores to a high score table
    Dim table = _
        userScores _
        .OrderByDescending(Function(user) user.Score) _
        .Select(Function(user, i) New With {.Index = i + 1, .User = user}) _
        .GroupBy(Function(row) row.User.Score) _
        .SelectMany(
            Function(group)
                Dim position = group.First().Index
                Return group.Select(
                    Function(row)
                    Return New With {.Position = position, .User = row.User}
                End Function)
            End Function)
    ' Print results
    For Each row In table
        Console.WriteLine("{0} {1} {2}", row.Position, row.User.Score, row.User.Name)
    Next
```

Here the users are ordered (descending) by score. Then an index is given to each user. The users are then grouped by score. Finally the groups are flattened using SelectMany, with the position for each row being assigned from the the first row in the group's index value.

Comment: Please sir, how can i implement this solution in my databound datagridview. i have one blank  column for Position which is not bound to any datafield. my datagrid columns look like this  Names TotalScore Position. i want each person position to display on position column. THANKS